# Display user#show url as www.fb.com/usrname and www.usrname.fb.com instead of showing www.fb.com/123, in rails 4.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to show username instead of user_id i.e., (users/4).

i have tried with changing routes file, model file as:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param 
    username
  end
end
```

and routes file as:

```
get '/:username' => 'users#show'
```

on **show action** it must show as fb.com/username url.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you don't need to mention '/:username' to routes, rails will automatically take username instead of id, when you override to_param method.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem for this. Here is Rails cast : [Pretty URLs with friendly_id](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid) On how to use it. You can use the attribute/column you want in the URL.

With FriendlyId, it's easy to make your application use URLs like:

```
http://example.com/states/washington
```

instead of:

```
http://example.com/states/4323454
```

Comment: without using gem?